# Google Apps: Access to domain users' contacts as an admin

Tags: google-data-api, google-contacts-api

As a Google Apps administrator, I would like to add specific contacts to all my users' address books.

Which API should I be looking at? As I understand, the Contacts API requires the user to be logged in as the user who's address book I'm trying to modify. In my case, I can only be logged in as the administrator. I can also pass in the administrator's credentials (as is the case for all of the provisioning APIs).

I prefer to use the .Net libraries, if possible.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add them to be shared for all the domain you can use this application:
http://code.google.com/p/google-shared-contacts-client/
which imports contacts from CSV into the shared contacts (it takes 24 hours).

Or you can create your own application, personally I made 2 programs and used for on python and for the other php(although google doesn't offer for php a gdata library you can [find one from Zend](http://framework.zend.com/download/gdata/)).

If you want to add them to specific users  you need to write your own code there is no application I know of, and use a Oauth 2.0 login to login on their behalf (as long as you are administrator of that google domain) to use the API in their name. Personally I didn't dealt with this [but received an answer that is possible](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-contacts-api/1_KHoy37dQo%5B1-25%5D) ) . Connecting with their name and password is only one of the authentication types called: clientlogin , but there are also other ways you can connect on their behalf.